# Which person does King Roedran of Murandy resemble?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

According to the below quote, Ashaman and Rand think King Roedran of Murandy resembles someone. Who is this person?

> King Roedran of Murandy was one of the last to enter the tent, and
>   Egwene noticed something curious as he did. Several of Rand’s
>   Asha’man— Narishma, Flinn, Naeff—moved in behind Roedran. Others, near
>   Rand, looked as alert as cats who had seen a wolf wander by.
>
> Rand stepped over to the shorter, wider man and looked down into his
>   eyes. Roedran stuttered for a moment, then started wiping his brow
>   with a handkerchief. Rand continued to stare at him.
>
> “What is it?” Roedran demanded. “You’re the Dragon Reborn, so they
>   say. I do not know that I'd have let you—”
>
> “Stop,” Rand said, raising a finger.
>
> Roedran quieted immediately.
>
> “Light burn me,” Rand said. “You’re not him, are you?”
>
> “Who?” Roedran asked.
>
> Rand turned away from him, waving his hand to make Narishma and the
>   others stand down. They did so reluctantly. “I thought for certain . .
>   .” Rand said, shaking his head. “Where are you?”

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They think he could be Demandred.  This was one of the most popular fan theories for where Demandred is hiding.  It seemed logical because many of the other Forsaken had replaced rulers.  He also gave Talmanes an expensive pipe as a gift, and some thought this was being used to track the Band of the Red Hand.  Brandon Sanderson has said this comment by Rand was not intended as a reference to the fan theory, but that Rand would have drawn the same conclusions that many of us did - he knew that ruling was the Forsaken's style, and that Roedran was one of the few rulers he hadn't interacted with yet.

Comment: yeah, Demandred is at this point, the only Male forsaken that has yet to show himself, and so Rand assumed that it must be Roedran since he is the only world leader not yet accounted for.